# Initializing a view without findViewById()

Tags: java, android, layout, view, fragment

I have an activity and a fragment. Now in the onCreate() of the fragment I want to add rows to my table layout defined in the xml of the fragment. For that I want to initialize a table layout to that defined in the xml. In the view of my application I only have the layout of the main activity set. I don't have the view of the fragment and I can't set it right now. So when I wrote this

```
  TableLayout tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.record);
```

there is an error in the log cat. View can't be found. I understand the problem but I am not able to find its solution anywhere.

record is the id of the table layout in fragment's layout xml file

```
<TableLayout

        android:id="@+id/record"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TableLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By doing a lot of research I finally found the solution to my own problem.

For this I used a layout inflater

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, null);
    TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.record);
```